# heroku: Deploying angular app inside spring boot app

Tags: heroku, deployment

I've one repo sunixi and it has two projects sun-angular(angular) and sun-admin(spring boot) in ts-admin i'm building ts-angular via executions and moving dist into resources/static of sun-admin project after that i'm building the sun-admin. On local enviroment it is working fine but how can i do same in heroku deployment.

structure of repo
sunixi
---sun-angular
---sun-admin

in sun-admin i'm setting workingDirectory as ../sun-angular but while deploying to heroku i'm getting

```
Cannot run program "npm" (in directory "/tmp/build_02607c07/sun-angular"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a monorepository strategy, an option is to use subdir buildpack to select where is the path of your folder: https://github.com/timanovsky/subdir-heroku-buildpack

If you want to deploy backend and frontend in the same heroku app, the project folder should contains a npm package. Otherwise, i will not work.

Comment: thank you . 

i'm sorry can u please elaborate a little so i can understand better.

Comment: Using buildpacks:        
https://github.com/timanovsky/subdir-heroku-buildpack        
heroku/java        

Subdir buildpack app detected        
Subdir buildpack in sunixi 
created tmp dir: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/subdirmDIT0        
moving working dir: ts-admin to /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/subdirmDIT0        
/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/subdirmDIT0 to build dir /tmp/build_f77cdc82        
remote:        cleaning tmp dir /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/subdirmDIT0        
Java app detected        
Installing Maven 3.6.2...tar: sunixi-angular: Cannot open: No such file or directory